# Apache not loading document root correctly

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, apache2.4

Apache shows default page and doesn't load site configuration. OS: Debian 10.

Site is enabled but somehow it doesn't show files from public_html folder. Any help is appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
ServerName abc.com
ServerAlias *.abc.com
DocumentRoot /home/xx/public_html

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /home/xx/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/xx/ssl.key

<Directory /home/xx/public_html>
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/xx/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/xx/logs/access.log common
LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

No enough reputation to comment, so I’m trying with an answer and will clean it up if useful.

No mention of what you’re finding, if anything, in your logs. I assume you’re accessing using HTTPS to be sure your requests are going to port 443, but if per chance you were not I would try that first by specifying the protocol when entering the URL in your browser - otherwise you are probably making your request *to the server* on port 80 and ***not*** 443 where your `VirtualHost` is listening.

`http://example.com` ====> browser sends request to port 80, default port for `http`
`https://example.com` ====> browser sends request to port 443, default port for `https`

Is there also a `VirtualHost` entry for port 80 to redirect those requests to 443? If your browser is trying to load it as `http` using port 80 first then perhaps that’s why you’re seeing the Apache default page as I believe the server will be attempting to serve from `/var/www/html/` for requests on port 80 unless you have already pointed these elsewhere with another `VirtualHost`, etc.

An example of what I mean that I have in use; either the `ReWriteEngine` or the `Redirect permanent` may be redundant, but I can confirm it functions fine for me as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

For my setup, I preferred that the `www` subdomain be default and set up DNS intentionally to treat it as such, so the bare domain is `ServerAlias` in my instance.

Comment: Hello, shouldn't the <VirtualHost *:443> take care of it?  Where do you define Apache to look for 443 besides the place where i mentioned?

Comment: You are correct that this is what would have Apache look to port 443; however, if you're not specifying the ```https://``` protocol when attempting to load the site in your browser my suspicion is that it's being treated as a regular ```http``` request on port 80 and would be going to the default ```/var/www/html/``` instead (unless there were other directives for port 80, then it would go to the defined locations for those).

For my server, I have specifically included an ```<VirtualHost:80>``` entry to push any stray ```http``` attempt to be redirected to `https.`

Comment: I am already doing http to https rewrite at cloudflare and apache level. Are you saying without 80 port, rewrite on apache will not even work? If that's the case, I might use firewall redirect.